# How to send delete request and inspect the Capybara::Session instead of the Rack::Response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, rack-test

I'm testing with cucumber, capybara and rack-test.

I want to send a delete request and then inspect the response.

I've found that the method `visit(url)` store the response in the object `page` which is a `Capybara::Session`.

Now I'm sending the delete request with the method `delete url` and then `follow_redirect!`. The problem here is that these methods store the response in the object `last_response` which is a `Rack::MockResponse`.

My web steps are built using the `page` object but I can't find the way to send delete request and storing the response in `page`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Capybara driver via:

```
page.driver.delete
```